# Limiting distribution of infinite sparse sum

Tags: central-limit-theorem, sum

Let $N$ be a positive integer.
I consider $N$ random variables $X_1^{(N)}, X_2^{(N)}, \dots, X_N^{(N)}$, all independent and identically distributed, each taking values $\pm 1$ with probabilities $p/(2N)$ and $0$ with probability $1-p/N$.
Consider the sum:

$$Z_N = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^{(N)}$$

I am interested in the limiting probability distribution of $Z_N$, as $N\rightarrow\infty$. Denote by $Z$ a random variable following this limit distribution. Note that $Z$ should have a well-defined distribution. I can compute its first few moments, since:

$$\langle Z_N\rangle = \langle Z\rangle = 0, \quad
\langle Z_N^2\rangle = \langle Z^2\rangle = p$$

However I don't think I can apply the central limit theorem, because the distribution of the $X_i^{(N)}$ is changing with $N$.

So how can I compute the limiting form of the distribution of $Z$?

Comment: $X_N,$ being a discrete random variable, has no density, whence its density has no limiting form: it sounds like you want to compute the limiting *distribution function,* should it exist at all. Are you willing to standardize the $X_N$ if necessary?

Comment: @whuber Yes, I want the distribution. Using "density" was incorrect. Here standardizing would just mean dividing by $\hat p$, which I think will not help much.

Comment: Please note, writing $p_N =\hat{p}/N$ for all indexes $N,$ that the variance of $X_N$ is $$\operatorname{Var}(X_N)=\sum_{i=1}^N\operatorname{Var}(x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^N p_i\approx \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\hat p}{i}=\hat{p}H_i\approx \hat{p}\log(N)$$ where $H_i$ are the harmonic numbers.

Comment: @whuber Ah, I see the confusion. Thanks for being explicit. Maybe my notation was not clear enough. In the problem I am formulating, for a given $N$, the variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$ are all independent and **identically** distributed. I'll try to rewrite the question and answer with a notation that makes this dependence more explicit.

Comment: @whuber Please see edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer.

The moment generating function of $Z_N$ is given by:

$$\psi_N (\zeta) = \langle e^{\zeta Z_N} \rangle = \left( 1 +
\frac{p}{N} [\cosh (\zeta) - 1] \right)^N$$

Taking the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$, we obtain the moment-generating function of $Z$:

$$\psi(\zeta) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \psi_N (\zeta) 
= \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{p}{N} [\cosh(\zeta) - 1] \right)^N
= e^{p \cosh (\zeta) - p}$$

Sow now I just need to take the inverse Fourier transform of $\psi(i\zeta)$, but I can't get the integral done.

Comment: This answer looks inconsistent with the question: the question supposes $p$ varies with $N$ but you don't introduce any such variation.  It would help to use clearer notation in both the question and the answer so that it explicitly shows how both $p$ and $X$ vary.  This answer looks more like part of the question: I suggest you move it into the question itself.

Comment: @whuber Note that $p = \hat p / N$, and I assume that $\hat p$ remains finite. That answers your question?

Comment: No: I don't have any questions.  My comments were aimed at showing why your calculations are incorrect.

Comment: @whuber I don't see what's incorrect. I *do* consider the variation of $p$ with $N$ in this answer.

Comment: Yes, but your notation prevents you from considering it correctly, unless I misunderstand the question--but that, too, is an issue of using appropriate notation.

Comment: @whuber I also updated the notation of this answer.